# Creating html "blocks" using <li> instead of <div>

Tags: html, css

I noticed that on Facebook profile pages, the left column (the one containing `About`, `Photos`, etc) is implements as an ordered list, with each "block" represented as a list item.

In my own projects, I've done this sort of thing but creating multiple `<div>`s of the same class.

I couldn't figure out though why Facebook chose this way.

Is there any particular reason that anyone knows of?

I'm thinking that there must be some advantages that would be handy to know about.

Comment: I think it will be argued back and forth until the world ends.  I personally would code those using `<div>` because I think they are blocks, and not navigation.  But the feed uses the same html, and I think that is correct, because that is a list of items.  Maybe that's why they did it - reusable code? Interesting question, don't think you'll get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the proper way of doing it.  When there are elements that should be grouped like navigation, it's cleaner to have together in a list.  Screen readers, search engines and such understand your content better this way as well. You can make things look the same through CSS, but the way the code is interpreted for the visually impaired, by robots, etc is key to the overall experience.

Comment: But interestingly, in the 'photos' block, they consider the block itself a list-item (as the question says), but the grid of photos inside it is in a `<table>`, and that isn't tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` tags only say that the contained elements are some sort of html block. `<ul><li>` tags assert that this that is a related list of items.

It is true that normally we think of browsers as showing `<ul><li>` as a bulleted list. There is actually no requirement that list be bulleted.

In Twitter Bootstrap

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
```

Is the code to start a pulldown menu. Twitter can reflow the `<ul><li>` into a nested list if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using unordered lists as navigation is something I've seen for a long time, to the point of becoming a convention. From what I've read, its mostly for simplicity, semantics, and organization, but it also allows for Textreader navigation and is more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The html blocks on the Facebook page you're talking about is basically a navigation bar, which is a list of links. The  element does just this. The formatting has been styled quite a bit to make it look like proper buttons.

It's a convention do it this way, and it's convenient because you won't have to create links in your div elements yourself.

You can read some more on W3Schools about this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp